# why does gcc search in /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu before /usr/include

Tags: gcc

The gcc manual says that the order of search for system headers for C (not C++) compilation is:

```
   /usr/local/include
 libdir/gcc/target/version/include
 /usr/target/include
 /usr/include
```

yet on my system it shows preference for

```
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/
```

before

```
/usr/include
```

Why??

On my system, I only have the first , and 4th directory, and my header file in question is only in the 4th.  So where does

```
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

come into the search???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The manual says that is the system header search order for *a normal Unix system*. It can't always be exactly true for all Unix and Linux hosts, even with appropriate replacement of the place-holders `libdir` and `target`. And it is not unknown for significant typos, anachronisms or laxities to persist for years in GNU docs.

In your case, `target` = `x86_64-linux-gnu` and `libdir` most probably =
`/usr/lib`. For `/usr/target/include` read `/usr/include/target`,
for your linux distro (as for mine). With that transposition, you actually
do have the third directory, and it becomes correct for `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/` to
precede `/usr/include` in your search order.

Your headline question was *why* that precedence, and user1666959 answers
that, if not the one you concluded with.

Comment: Thank you Mike I think this is it. As for the other answer, I will disagree - I can't put all details in the headline, that is what the body of the message is for, he can't just answer the headline without looking at the body.

Answer (score 1):

Think of it this way: you want to have the include file most specific to your system first. Same with compilation, if you know you are on a x86_64, use instructions/constructs available on that architecture (SSEn), that is likely to be the fastest, most efficient...if you don't have them fall back to the more general entities available: so most specific stuff gets searched and used first.

Comment: sorry, you don't understand my question, please read it carefully, and thank you for spending your valuable time